# How to open a file / path with the integer in it - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a script that automatically opens a series of csvs containing dataseries and save them down to a single dataframe yet I already have got a problem with opening paths that have integers in their names, i.e.

```
    abspath = os.path.abspath("..\..\Blog\Wpisy\7_Bitcoin")
    print(abspath)
```

Returns:

```
    C:\Blog\Wpisy_Bitcoin
```

Instead of:
C:\Blog\Wpisy\7_Bitcoin

The same applies when the file name has got an integer in it

Comment: It’s not the integer causing the issue, it’s the backslashes as they are an escape character.  Try it with forward slashes instead.

Comment: Or just double-backslash everything \\

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, the integer is not the issue, but rather, the backslashes, as a backslash is an escape character.

There are a couple options for you:

Option 1:
Prefix the string with an `r` for ‘raw string’.

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(r"..\..\Blog\Wpisy\7_Bitcoin")
```

Option 2:
Use forward slashes (recommended for portability).

```
abspath = os.path.abspath("../../Blog/Wpis/7_Bitcoin")
```

Option 3:
Escape the backslashes with another backslash.

```
abspath = os.path.abspath("..\\..\\Blog\\Wpisy\\7_Bitcoin")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use raw strings to avoid `\` beeing interpreted as an escape sequence or use `/` for path assembly (see [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for easy conversion between windows and posix paths)

- For raw string: use `r"..\..\Blog\Wpisy\7_Bitcoin"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.path.join`:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..", "..", "Blog", "Wpisy", "7_Bitcoin"))
print(abspath)
```

It will automatically add slashes to your path.